# PHP override error

Tags: php, overriding

I'm trying to override a method but I get an error, that the function could not be found.
Here's an example:

```
abstract class a {
    public function build(){
        $this._loadComponents();
        return $this;
    }

    abstract protected function _loadComponents();
}

class b extends a {
    protected function _loadComponents(){
        echo "test";
    }
}
$b = new B();
$b->build();
```

Results in: Fatal error: Call to undefined function

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$this.` on line 3 should be `$this->`

Comment: also, php is case sensitive, so `class b` should be `class B` and `return this;` needs to be `return $this;` , i dont know why you do that though, returning the object makes no sense there

Comment: @x4rf41 PHP is not case sensitive for anything except variables and some constants. Class and function names are case-insensitive.

Comment: @DaveRandom i have been programming PHP for about 10 years and i didnt know that. PHP is so weird sometimes :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this.` on line 3 should be `$this->`. `.` is a concatenation operator in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$this->_loadComponents();
```

instead of

```
$this._loadComponents();
```

dot(.) operator is used to concatinate two or more string where as this(->) operator is used for accesing class properties and functions.

Answer (score 0):

In php `.` is a concatenation marker, you should use `$this->_loadComponents()`

Answer (score 0):

Do look this:

```
<?php
abstract class a {
    public function build(){
        $this->_loadComponents();
        return $this;
    }

    abstract protected function _loadComponents();
}

class b extends a {
    protected function _loadComponents(){
        echo "test";
    }
}
$b = new B();
$b->build();
?>
```